# Why cannot authenticate a user using Auth::atempt in Laravel?

Tags: php, redirect, frameworks, laravel

This is routes file and $users shows the values but login fails

```
Route::post('login', function () {


    $user = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );



    if(Auth::attempt($user))
        {
        return Redirect::to('profile')
            ->with('flash_notice', 'You are successfully logged in.');
         }
    else
    {
    // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
        return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('flash_error', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect.')
            ->withInput();
    }
});
```

Modal:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }



    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Comment: How is the password stored in the DB?  it should be encrypted with `Bcrypt` in the DB, not stored as plain text.

Comment: tht hash n encryption part is done in model

Comment: can you also post the model, to see if the encryption on the model has any issues

Comment: Adding some debug to your code will help you (`Log::debug($msg)`).. then you can manually check that the encrypted password you're passing to `check()` is the same as what you have in the DB

Comment: m new 2 laravel
dnt knw hw 2 use hash n bcrypt properly..I have tried it by seeing various blogs but still errors..
please suggest me asap the properly tested runnable code

Comment: Log::debug($msg) 
when I cal ths error is thr tht " undefined variable:msg "

Comment: yeah.. that was just an example.. replace $msg with what you want to appear in your logs.. :)

Comment: is the password on the DB encrypted?

Comment: Make sure when creating a user, you hash their password: `$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('txtPassword'));`

Comment: after hashing d password still the same error

Comment: Maybe you set the password field to `varchar(32)`... set it to a larger value maybe `varchar(60)`.

Comment: I dnt think it matters when I am personally inserting a password of 5 characters

Comment: no the password in DB is not encrypted

Comment: It does matter, because in the database, the password will be hashed and much longer. You should set your password fields to be 60-70 chars (as a varchar) in your database.

Comment: @user2655547,  When you say the password in the DB is not encrypted, how have you created the user? When you create the user ensure your password is encrypted using `Hash::make(Input::get('txtPassword'));`. It is necessary that you password is encrypted using `Hash::make` because the `Auth::attempt` internally validates on your DB with the encrypted password.

Answer (score 1):

When using the authentication mechanism provided by Laravel you should pass the following check list:

1. The database column where you store the password should be a string with a length of **60 characters**.
2. The password should be stored *encrypted*, no plain. Since we are talking about BCrypt it has to be a value similar to: `$2a$10$KssILxWNR6k62B7yiX0GAe2Q7wwHlrzhF3LqtVvpyvHZf0MwvNfVu`.
3. You have to configure the security mechanism by editing the file located `app/config/auth.php`.

After that, you will eventually have your problem solved.